# What does the TIE designation used in the Empire's starfighters names mean?

Tags: star-wars, names

Is there a specific meaning behind the TIE designation used in the names for the Galactic Empire's starfighters (TIE Bomber, TIE Fighter, and TIE Interceptor) and if so what is it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78581/discussion-on-question-by-royalmurder-what-does-the-tie-designation-used-in-the).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

TIE stands for **[Twin Ion Engine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TIE_Line)** - sub-light propulsion technology behind these small fighter/bomber crafts.

TIE itself is not initially associated with the Empire, but the Empire commissioned these fighters on such a large scale that it made them their signature craft during the Galactic Civil War.

**Out-of-universe**, the name was coined by George Lucas, because they look like a bow tie.

<sub>From [Wiki Legends article on TIE Series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TIE_Series), also [here](http://usoproject.blogspot.com/2011/02/ben-burtt-about-genesis-of-tie-fighter.html)</sub>

> Though the term "TIE Fighter" was coined because George Lucas thought they looked like bow ties, the ion engine is a real-life type of spacecraft propulsion, and publicity surrounding the launch of the SMART-1 spacecraft, particularly the shuttle Smart-1, likened its ion thruster to the propulsion systems of a TIE Fighter.

Comment: Of course real-life ion thrusters have incredibly low acceleration, but can run for ages on a small amount of fuel/power. The complete opposite of the TIE engines.

Comment: There are many examples of real world science/tech terms misuse in Star Wars universe, most notable is Han's boast about The Falcon being able to complete The Kessel Run in 12 parsecs, where parsec was interpreted as a measure of time, not distance. It was later retconned with a whole story about a smart pilot being able to navigate the route in a shorter distance, thus faster.

Comment: @TimSparrow That retcon has been reinforced by the Kessel Run being featured in the new "Solo" movie, under circumstances that make it seem *more* impressive than the original retcon, but means that the original quote (**Ben Kenobi:** *Yes indeed, if it's a fast ship* **Han Solo:** *Fast ship? [..] It's the ship that made the Kessel Run in less than twelve parsecs*) makes *less* sense.

Comment: @Chronocidal Is it possible for that to make less sense, what with the parsec being a unit of distance an' all?

Comment: @DavidRicherby In the ancient Greek epic, *Argonautica*, Jason and his crew take their ship (the *Argo*) through [the Clashing Rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplegades).  Taking this shortcut required that their ship be fast enough to get through before the rocks could reopen and then clash together again to crush the ship - meaning that because of a combination of Jason's cleverness and the Argo's **speed** they could complete their journey in a shorter **distance**, and thus time.

Comment: @Chronocidal I applaud your erudition and lateral thinking, but that's mighty contrived. :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Star Wars was heavily based on the Epic style and the Hero's Journey, compared to the light-fantasy Sci-Fi contemporaneous with its release.  Adding a reference to Jason and the Argo (pretty much *the* most famous ship this side of Noah's Ark until relatively recently) isn't *excessively* convoluted.  (Similarly:  The Empire as the Olympians, with the Death Star as Mt Olympus and Emperor Palpatine as Zeus)

Comment: @DavidRicherby In old canon before Disney discarded it, the Kessel Run involved going around a cluster of black holes called The Maw. Paths closer to The Maw were shorter but more dangerous, requiring a faster ship to not get trapped by the heavy gravity. Contrived, yes, but it does explain the quote.

Comment: @Chronocidal and Palps hurls lightning.... Mind... Blown...

Comment: @Douglas We learned from Intersteller that travelling closer to a black hole causes gravity well time dilation and actually is a _longer_ trip as experienced by the outside world. So going around would actually take less time from the point of view of the source and destination.

Answer (score 14):

## Twin Ion Engine

This is mentioned in various canon sources but the easiest one for me to reference from is [*Star Wars Encyclopedia of Starfighters and Other Vehicles*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Encyclopedia_of_Starfighters_and_Other_Vehicles). This includes the following pages where the TIE Striker and TIE Reaper have their models referred to as "Twin Ion Engine striker x1" and "Twin Ion Engine reaper".

[image: Star Wars Encyclopedia of Starfighters and Other Vehicles, TIE Fighter and TIE Reaper]

Answer (score 2):

From the [Star Wars wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TIE_Series):

> The TIE series derived its name from the SIE-TIE [twin ion engine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Twin_ion_engine/Legends) (...)
>
> [from the link above] The twin ion engine system was a sublight drive system that was first invented about the time of the Jedi Civil War.

Comment: You do realise you've linked to Legends right?

Comment: is there another canon ?

Comment: We're talking about engines here, not cannons. d;

Comment: @aslum - TIE fighters do in fact [have two cannons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TIEfighter.jpg) though.

Comment: @T.E.D. Wooosh.

Comment: @T.E.D. They thought about naming them Twin Ion Cannon fighters, but the controls on the TIC fighters proved to be too jerky for pilots to handle :P

Comment: @aslum - ... **and** they make that noise (with a bit of a scream added). You're on a roll today!